# Binding silverlight UI property to source

Tags: silverlight

I have a checkbox which i need to bind to a bool in the source and also disable or enable a container.

My source is as follows for the binding but it does not work:

```
private bool isMapEditOn = false;

OnLoadFunction()
{
    //Bindings
    Binding mapEditBind = new Binding("IsChecked") { Source = isMapEditOn, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };

    //Bind to check or uncheck the mapEdit Checkbox
    ChckEditMap.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, mapEditBind);
    //Bind to disable children (point and area buttons).
    EditBtnContainer.SetBinding(IsEnabledProperty, mapEditBind);
}
```

When I test this by checking and unchecking the checkbox, it does not altar isMapEditOn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap the `isMapEditOn` in a property. If you want change notification from the source you'll need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (not shown here. See [this](http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/How-to-implement-INotifyPropertyChanged-interface.aspx) page for info on implementing this interface ):

```
private bool _isMapEditOn = false;

public bool IsMapEditOn
{
    get
    {
        return _isMapEditOn;
    }
    set
    {
        _isMapEditOn = value;
    }
}

OnLoadFunction()
{
    //Bindings
    Binding mapEditBind = new Binding("IsMapEditOn") { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };

    //Bind to check or uncheck the mapEdit Checkbox
    ChckEditMap.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, mapEditBind);
    //Bind to disable children (point and area buttons).
    EditBtnContainer.SetBinding(IsEnabledProperty, mapEditBind);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the type bool? instead of bool.  The IsChecked property is defined as:

```
public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
```

Comment: I changed private bool isMapEditOn = false; to private bool? isMapEditOn = false; and it does not work if thats what you were talking about.